# Is PHP session expired in "Google App Engine"?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Session expires too soon on a *Google App* project when I am working on, even after editing the `max gc lifetime` in the `php.ini`.

I would want it to expire after 7 seven days, but it seems to have a max expiry of less than 5 hours.

Answer (score 1):

By default, App Engine stores session data in memcache.

The free memcache tier has no guaranteed lifetime, which might be affecting you.

I recommend moving to persistent session storage (Datastore/CloudSQL).

Comment: thank you Tom, that sounds a bit like greek, how do you move sessions to CloudSQL /Datastore?

Comment: You need to implement an alternative session handler. Here is some info on the PHP site. http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php and here from Google. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime#PHP_Sessions